# Package geometry warning

Tags: geometry, warnings

I'm creating custom graph paper, and my code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=10mm,
    right=10mm,
    top=10mm,
}

\SetBgContents%
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,color=gray,step=0.5cm] (current page.south 
    west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, double, rounded corners, scale=2, text height=25pt, 
anchor=north west, align=center] (15,0) {Name: 
\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_ \\ Date: \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Which works, except it gives two errors:

> Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.`width' (483.69684pt) is ignored.

and

> Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.`height' (731.23582pt) is ignored.

I'm not really sure what is causing this, or how to fix it. Could someone explain?

I looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211050/how-to-eliminate-over-specification-in-h-and-v-warning-in-geometry-package), but I didn't really understand the explanation given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

You call a first time geometry with option  `margin=25mm`, then load it again and specify `left=10mm, right=10mm, top=10mm`. This contradicts the previous option, since margin=25mm means

`left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm`.

Furthermore, you specify `height` and `width`. But width is what remains from `paper width` after you've substracted   `left + right`. Actually,  you have no choice, and this specification will be ignored.

Comment: I think so.  `total=` is the same as `body`+ optionally `margins` if I remember well?

Comment: okay. I also deleted the [margin=25mm] specification, as it was not necessary. It now works perfectly.